# Find ES6-module in which entity is declared

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2, ecmascript-harmony

***TL;DR* There is some imported entity on ES6-module. Should find original ES module and line number, where this entity has been initially declared - not re-imported / re-exported.**

There is some hierarchy of nested imported ES6-modules, some of which are not controlled by library code and had been imported from well-known place - it's some user-side configuration file.

Imagine following files structure:

***config.js*** (not controlled)

```
import nested from './nested';
export default { 
    param1: { aaa: 10, bbb: 20  },
    param2: nested
}
```

***nested.js***  (not controlled)

```
export default { 
    ccc: 30,
    ddd: 40
}
```

***index.js***  (controlled)

```
import config from './config'
const ddd = config.ddd;
if(notValid(ddd)) {
    const decl = %FIND_DECLARATION%(ddd);
    console.log('Config variable "config.ddd" is not valid');
    console.log('You declared it here: ', decl);
}
```

Output should be like following

```
You declared it here: 
File webpack://./nested.js , line 2
    ddd: 40
    ^^^^^^^
```

Should write function `%FIND_DECLARATION%`, which can find original ES-module and line number for some object declaration, and retrieve it's source code

Environment is **webpack**. Any dirty hacks are welcome if can't be solve without it.

Comment: where is your webpack file

Comment: Most likely, proposed task can't be solved by such approach. Instead, original end-user code should be transformed to inject mapping meta-information declarations. 
Most closest solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725120/modify-objects-in-es6-source-code-by-webpack-babel