# Modify objects in ES6 source code by webpack/babel

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

There is ES6-application which is bundled with webpack and babel plugins. Is it possible to modify some source code, to inject hidden field in every object?

Some babel/webpack plugins, including webpack-replace-plugin and babel-minify-replace, allows to interop field accessing and create some macro-definitions

But problem is wrap all object creation, and insert some field with unique name. It should be everywhere - in object creation literals, in rest-spread copy and so on, so naïve replace by regular expression is not solution.

Original code:

```
const obj1 = { aaa:10, bbb:20  };
const obj2 = new Object();
const obj3 = { ...obj1, ddd: 20 };
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const str = new String("ABC");
```

Transformed code:

```
const obj1 = { aaa:10, bbb:20, SECRET_PROPERTY: true  };
const obj2 = new Object(); obj2.SECRET_PROPERTY = true;
const obj3 = { ...obj1, ddd: 20, SECRET_PROPERTY: true };
const arr = [1, 2, 3]; arr.SECRET_PROPERTY = true;
const str = new String("ABC"); str.SECRET_PROPERTY = true;
```

Of course, such operation will decrease optimization of original code, and it's required only for debug/development mode.

**Update**: Have found babel plugin, which has closest functionality for original task - https://github.com/JonAbrams/elsa . It perform different task, but can easily adapted for original task

Comment: Sure, you could write your own babel plugin to do that.

Comment: @FelixKling Of course! Maybe, some plugin for this purposes had already existed? Or there is some plugin with similar functionality, which can be forked and adapted for original task?

Comment: Maybe, but asking for software recommendations is off topic.

Comment: What if some of the code has logic that iterates over properties and breaks if there are unexpected values? Injecting new properties on random objects seems super likely to break stuff.

Comment: @loganfsmyth It seems that it can be two levels of solution for that issue. First level will likely cover most use cases. It based on `Object.defineProperty` operation with `enumerable: false` option, so that property will not shown in default `Object.keys` or `for-of` loops. Another way is use `Symbol` properties. Of course, secret key can be retrieved by `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`, but it is specific use case per se.

Comment: @loganfsmyth More that, if first level described above is not enough, there is absolute way. Transform plugin should declare `WeakMaps` in all end-used modules and set referred objects as key there, and as value information about secret property. Then all secret `WeakMaps` should be exported recursive way, through own library code. Because `export` bindings are not iterable, passing secret export name through library will get bucket of `WeakMap`s. Then, if some end-user object is appeared, it can be searched in WeakMap repository, and secret field will be retrieved

Comment: @loganfsmyth But thanks anyway for remember about it, think first level should be implemented anyway, and second level if some issues will be found after transplating end-user code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task had been solved by manually writing `babel` plugin, which performs prior modification of source code, and inject meta-information for each live object, including original file name, line and columns in that file, and string representation of object declaration

Plugin is provided as function on gist: https://gist.github.com/IhostVlad/9310188edbdbc9f62dc3107417cc8fe4

Typical usage with `webpack` is following

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    webpackServerConfig.module.rules.forEach(rule =>
        rule.loaders.filter(({ loader }) => loader === 'babel-loader').forEach(
            loader =>
                (loader.query.presets = [
                    {
                        plugins: [babelPluginObjectSource]
                    }
                ].concat(Array.isArray(loader.query.presets) ? loader.query.presets : []))
        )
    );
}
```

Where `webpackServerConfig` is original webpack config for production mode, and `babelPluginObjectSource` is imported referred above babel-plugin

Then is runtime meta-information for each object `obj` from client code will be available via `obj.__SOURCE_DELCARATION__` property

Comment: Also, plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-source-wrapper can also be used for solution same tasks, but it has caveat: does not include source code in meta-object. For some tasks it may be good, but if source code had been processed by `ES6`-like babel presets, and then packed into webpack bundle, there is no way to retrieve original source code. But it mandatory for verbose error handling for end user, which was original task